# Max of sum query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query that will list student(s) enrolled with the maximum total credit points.

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT s.S_ID,
       s.S_LAST,
       s.S_FIRST,
       s."Total Credits"
FROM
  (SELECT q2.S_ID,
          q2.S_LAST,
          q2.S_FIRST,
          sum(q1.CREDITS) "Total Credits"
   FROM
     (SELECT COURSE_NO,
             CREDITS
      FROM COURSE) q1
   JOIN
     (SELECT s.S_ID,
             s.S_LAST,
             s.S_FIRST,
             cs.COURSE_NO
      FROM STUDENT s
      JOIN ENROLLMENT e ON s.S_ID = e.S_ID
      JOIN COURSE_SECTION cs ON e.C_SEC_ID = cs.C_SEC_ID) q2 ON q1.COURSE_NO = q2.COURSE_NO
   GROUP BY q2.S_ID,
            q2.S_LAST,
            q2.S_FIRST) q3
GROUP BY s.S_ID,
         s.S_LAST,
         s.S_FIRST,
         s."Total Credits"
WHERE "Total Credits" = max("Total Credits");
```

This doesn't work I am getting this error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:   
*Action:
Error at Line: 23 Column: 1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your outer select is from `q3` not from `s` and your last `where` clause is incorrect

Comment: which database are you using? and do you want all students that have the most credits?

Comment: This is using Oracle SQL Developer. Yes, I want all students that have the most credits, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT q3.S_ID,
       q3.S_LAST,
       q3.S_FIRST,
      max( q3.Total Credits)
FROM
  (SELECT q2.S_ID,
          q2.S_LAST,
          q2.S_FIRST,
          sum(q1.CREDITS) Total Credits
   FROM
     (SELECT COURSE_NO,
             CREDITS
      FROM COURSE) q1
   JOIN
     (SELECT s.S_ID,
             s.S_LAST,
             s.S_FIRST,
             cs.COURSE_NO
      FROM STUDENT s
      JOIN ENROLLMENT e ON s.S_ID = e.S_ID
      JOIN COURSE_SECTION cs ON e.C_SEC_ID = cs.C_SEC_ID) q2 ON q1.COURSE_NO = q2.COURSE_NO
   GROUP BY q2.S_ID,
            q2.S_LAST,
            q2.S_FIRST) q3
GROUP BY q3.S_ID,
         q3.S_LAST,
         q3.S_FIRST;
```

Comment: @user3664923 still getting the same error another ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to tackle this by just using the group by and Sum(), and retrieve the result with an order by sum() with limit 1 or more depending on how many students your want.

This would eliminate the outer subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Naughty double posting of the same question! This is the answer I gave to your other posting, same thing still applies here.

I'm pretty sure (no Oracle machine to test this) that your alias is the problem:

```
sum(q1.CREDITS) Total Credits
```

Should be

```
sum(q1.CREDITS) "Total Credits"
```

And therefore

```
max( q3.Total Credits)
```

Should be

```
max( q3."Total Credits")
```

Or you could get rid of the space in the alias. But there may be more to it than that, as I say, I've no Oracle machine handy to test that out.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all the "noise" your query become

```
SELECT s.S_ID, s.S_LAST, s.S_FIRST, s."Total Credits"
FROM
  (SELECT ...
   FROM (...) q1
   JOIN (...) q2
  ) q3
GROUP BY s.S_ID, s.S_LAST, s.S_FIRST, s."Total Credits"
WHERE "Total Credits" = max("Total Credits");
```

It's easy to see that `s` is not visible from your main query, also in the `WHERE` condition you're confronting a detail with an aggregation, that's not possible (at least not that way)

Answer (score 0):

If you build your query one join at a time, you will notice, first, that you don't need any of those inline views. You can do it very simply with one CTE definition and a subquery.

```
WITH
student AS
( SELECT  1 s_id, 'Jones' s_last, 'Sally' s_first FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  2, 'Smith', 'Pete' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  3, 'DeThroned', 'Kate' FROM dual
),
enrollment AS
( SELECT  1 s_id, 10 c_sec_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  select  1, 11 FROM dual UNION ALL
  select  2, 11 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  3, 12 FROM dual
),
course_section AS
( SELECT  10 c_sec_id, 101 course_no FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  11, 102 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  12, 103 FROM dual
),
course AS
( SELECT  101 course_id, 1 credits FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  102, 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  103, 3 FROM dual
),
StudentCredit AS
( SELECT  s.s_id, s_last, s_first, sum( c.credits ) AS TotalCredits
  FROM    student s
  JOIN    enrollment e
    ON    e.s_id = s.s_id
  JOIN    course_section cs
    ON    cs.c_sec_id = e.c_sec_id
  JOIN    course c
    ON    c.course_id = cs.course_no
  GROUP BY s.s_id, s_last, s_first
)
SELECT  *
FROM    StudentCredit
WHERE   TotalCredits = (
          SELECT  MAX( TotalCredits )
          FROM    StudentCredit
        );
```